# Modifying a .txt file in java with specific conditions

Tags: java, text, editor

I'm writing a small Java code to modify a txt.

Here's what im trying to work with, we have this long file to be imported on our accountability system,  but it's generated with some information that really doesn't matter to the accountant and just makes his work harder.

The file comes in lines like this:

```
00;1;1;22012018;"1779";"C";0;0;139084;0;2;0;"RECEBTO TITULO 001/000664/02 - EDGAR ROSA DA TRINDADE";7;19247028000;4561000150;1;
```

And what im trying to do is to just remove the **001/** and the **/02** in the first line.

And the output would be like(2000+ lines):

```
00;1;1;22012018;"1779";"C";0;0;139084;0;2;0;"RECEBTO TITULO 000664 - EDGAR ROSA DA TRINDADE";7;19247028000;4561000150;1;
```

it isn't a fixed value so a cant just **.replaceall()** on the file. It varies from 2 to even 8 digits on both sides or spacings before/after the bar. like so **0000123 / 123**.

My questions are.

What kind of function or replacing parameter should i use to include all of the diversity of data it the files?

Comment: use a CSVParser to read ich line/column. get the column with the value you want to work with. use a proper regex to match the values and replace them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the file line by line and remove the char sequence with [java regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), then write them to a new file.

```
public class Example {

    private static final String PREFIX = "\\d+/";
    private static final String SUFFIX = "/.*-";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File target = new File("target.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(target);

        File source = new File("source.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(source);
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fileWriter.write(line.replaceFirst(PREFIX, "").replaceFirst(SUFFIX, " -"));
                fileWriter.write("\r\n");
            }
        }  finally {
            fileReader.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, almost exactly what i was looking for, but it would be better if on the right side i can replace everything till the "-", cause in some cases when there's a spacing, it won't replace.